# Menu is going left on IE8 but staying on correct position on IE9 and other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have a code in CSS like

CSS

```
#menu_option { width:100px; margin-left:-50px; }
```

In Mozila, and Google Chrome and IE9 The menu is on the right position in this code but in IE9 it is moving left and cutting down the images. So I applied

```
#menu_option { width:100px; margin: 0; }
```

And this code is running correctly on IE8 but the menu is moving to the right on Mozila, Chorome and IE9.

Please anyone suggest how can I apply both of the code or merge both together in CSS and specify   `#menu_option { width:100px; margin: 0; }` for IE8 and `#menu_option { width:100px; margin-left:-50px; }` for others.

Here is the picture I am getting in IE8 when I am applying  `#menu_option { width:100px; margin-left:-50px; }`

![enter image description here][1]

but in others(IE9,Chrome and Mozila) I am getting and this is the right one.

![enter image description here][2]

And if I apply margin 0 then It I am getting the 2nd photo on IE8 and on others the picture set is moving right like

![enter image description here][3]

Answer (score 0):

as a rule of thumb, if you want good browser compatibility, don't put width and margin/padding (left or right) in the same element (same with height and margin/padding top/bottom). IE tends to include margins and padding (and border) inside the width while other browsers don't. Try putting a container like a `<div>` around #menu_option and put the width there, and leave the margin in the internal element, just to see if it makes it any better.

I agree it sucks adding an extra element just for this, but just see if it works and then you can play around with things.

Comment: I have tried Thanks but not working. I saw some codes in CSS that people specify code for IE8 separately but I am not getting those codes right now by searching.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for the IE-specific comment codes.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
etc.
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Though I strongly recommend against using browser-dependent code like this, except as a last resort. Rodolfo's suggestion about separating divs is really the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you need a static width? Other than removing that, it may also help to position your element relatively, with `#menu_option {position: relative; left: 50px;}`, depending on what your putting this menu option into.

Comment: no. I can not apply position as then it will mess up on different monitor